# how to resolve logging out of memory error?

Tags: python, logging

I am getting above error in my docker container which only has automation scripts(python 2.7.11) and to log errors i am using logging package.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 885, in emit
self.flush()

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 845, in flush
self.stream.flush()
IOError: [Errno 12] Out of memory
```

else i see below error as launch_err
I got above error as launch_err for that docker container and all i see in log is this
"(:[Errno 12] Out of memory [/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor/supervisord.py|runforever|235] [/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor/dispatchers.py|handle_read_event|232] [/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor/dispatchers.py|record_output|166] [/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor/dispatchers.py|_log|142] [/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor/loggers.py|info|275] [/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor/loggers.py|log|293] [/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor/loggers.py|emit|86] [/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor/loggers.py|handleError|90]

that container has 1GB mem , i tried increasing upto 4GB but it still crashes and logs same error. I believe its memory leak from logging package where its not able to release handlers to flush buffers.

Comment: Only two things to do when running out of memory - get more or use less.

Comment: It's very hard to see where your code is using so much memory if you don't post it.

Comment: Can you read through `/var/log/messages` ? (use `less /var/log/messages`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root cause was we were using epoch date function inside shell script which was being called every second. That caused hogging.